# DynamoDB pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services

I read through the DynamoDB [pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/) page and I'm a little confused about their free usage tier. Let's say a developer want's to get started on DynamoDB and he gets 100MB of free storage + 5 writes and 10 reads per second.

Since a table cannot be created below 5w/r5 capacity that would mean a developer trying DynamoDB can only create 2 tables at max.

That would also mean that if someone had to create several tables during development, they would have to pay about $7.50 (resp half if only 5w is used) a month for a table that sits there and more or less does nothing.

Is that correct?

Comment: I think this is something that only the DynamoDB folks could actually answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

The smallest provisioned throughput one can request has meanwhile been reduced to 1w/1r capacity units, see [Amazon DynamoDB - Reduced Minimum Throughput](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/amazon-dynamodb-reduced-minimum-throughput.html) for details, which specifically addresses the problem at hand:

> The [AWS Free Usage Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/?utm_source=AWSBlog&utm_medium=socialmedia&SM_AWS_Blog_DDBMin) allows you to consume up to 100 MB of DynamoDB
>   storage, 5 read capacity units, and 5 write capacity units per month.
>   **As a very beneficial side effect of today's announcement, you can now
>   create up to 5 tables within the Free Usage Tier**. *[emphasis mine]*

---

### Original Answer

> Since a table cannot be created below 5w/r5 capacity that would mean a
>   developer trying DynamoDB can only create 2 tables at max.

You are correct, as more clearly outlined in the respective FAQ entry [What is the minimum throughput I can provision for a single DynamoDB table?](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#What_is_the_minimum_throughput_I_can_provision_for_a_single_DynamoDB_table):

> The smallest provisioned throughput you can request is 5 write capacity units and 5 read capacity units.
>
> This falls within the free tier, which allows for 5 units of write capacity and 10 units of read capacity. The free tier applies to the
>   account level, not the table level. A given account may create a
>   single table with 5 units of write capacity and 10 units of read
>   capacity.

The resulting one table limitation might be considered a rather significant restriction concerning the other [AWS Free Usage Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) elements indeed, but on the other hand you can't handle serious real world scenarios with a single EC2 micro instance either (though technically [there are two available as of recently](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/01/aws-free-usage-tier-now-includes-microsoft-windows-on-ec2.html)).

The [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) use cases are clearly targeting respectively advanced scenarios, thus a free tier is probably not considered a necessity outside of testing scenarios.

> That would also mean that if someone had to create several tables
>   during development, they would have to pay about $7.50 (resp half if
>   only 5w is used) a month for a table that sits there and more or less
>   does nothing.

That's correct as well - by satisfying the advanced customer need for [provisioned throughput](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#What_is_provisioned_throughput), Amazon introduces a new pricing model, as summarized in section *Throughput Reservation* within the elaborate technical and business analysis [Amazon DynamoDB: First Look](http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2012/01/19/dynamodb/):

> This type of atomic service level provisioning is both differentiating
>   and compelling for certain customer types. Promising single digit
>   latency at a selected throughput level with zero customer effort
>   required is likely to be attractive for customers that require – or
>   think they require – a particular service level. And by requiring
>   customers to manually determine their required provisioning level,
>   Amazon stands to benefit from customer overprovisioning; customers
>   will feel pain if they’re under-provisioned and react, but conversely
>   may fail to observe that they’re over. Much like mobile carriers,
>   Amazon wins in both scenarios.

Again, this highlights the target market: customers with significant requirements and respectively guaranteed service level. Once you actually fall into that category, paying a small premium for an idling table *eventually* isn't going to be of any concern compared to the benefits of the service ;)

Comment: Amazon has since changed the minimum, it's now 1r/1w for table.

Comment: @Alan - thanks for pointing this out, I've updated the answer accordingly.